# Azure media service:Generate thumbnail with video encode

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I am using azure media service to generate encode,trim video. Now i want to generate video thumbnail with custom encoding preset. Here what i used to encode video and generate thumbnail:

```
{
"Version": "1.0",
  "Sources": [
    {
      "StartTime": "00:00:00",
      "Duration": "00:01:00"
    }
  ],
  "Codecs": [
    {
      "Type": "CopyVideo"
    },
    {
      "Type": "CopyAudio"
    },
    {
      "PngLayers": [
        {
          "Type": "PngLayer",
          "Width": 150,
          "Height": 150
        }
      ],
      "Start": "{Best}",
      "Type": "PngImage"
    }
  ],
  "Outputs": [
    {
      "FileName": "e3cb10a2-1580-49f7-ad29-99c44f5bc936_{Width}x{Height}_{VideoBitrate}.mp4",
      "Format": {
        "Type": "MP4Format"
      }
    },
    {
      "FileName": "{Basename}_{Index}{Extension}",
      "Format": {
        "Type": "PngFormat"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

while i am trying to encode video and generate thumbnail, getting this error:

> The preset results in multiple outputs with same name. Either use
>   unique file names or use macros to disambiguate!

Above code is work perfect if i remove thumbnail configuration and doing just video encoding.

Can any one suggest is it possible to generate thumbnail with `copyaudio` and `copyvideo` codecs?

Comment: This likely indicates that your input Asset has multiple video tracks. Are you using a live archive as the input Asset?

Comment: @AnilMurching Yes, first i uploaded asset and then using that asset as input asset for encoding

Comment: Can you please share the Job ID, and the data center you used? If you are willing to share the input content, then send us a link (SAS URL perhaps) to amshelp@microsoft.com. Thanks

Comment: @AnilMurching i have one new issue video gets upload twice. after successfull first upload and encode video get upload again automatically. Any idea?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "video get upload again". The service does not upload videos to your account. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @AnilMurching i am uploading video around 350 MB and it took 5-6 min, after about 4 min video upload start ageain. My service which upload video is hosted on azure. When i try hosting on iis then it works fine.  I think because of azure ajax ideal timeout. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps you could ask on a different forum?

Answer (score -1):

It's mandatory for Thumbnail generation to use the macro {Index} in the filename output.
  That shall solve the issue.
Regards,

Comment: This is a low quality answer. Why should use use macro `{Index}`? You should expand on this issue.